# Accepting only letters and no integers in C

Tags: c

I want to know how can I ensure that only characters are entered. Any ideas?

```
printf("Enter Customer Name");

scanf("%s",cname);
```

Comment: Like disallow entering non-characters symbol in terminal, or by checking entered result and asking to re-enter if entered symbols are not characters?

Comment: @rutsky I want to ask to reenter if symbols aren't characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can read in your string and then scan it using `isalpha()` or similar functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define STR(x) #x
#define SSTR(x) STR(x)
#define STR_FMT(x) "%" SSTR(x) "s"

#define CNAME_MAX_LEN 50

int inputName(char *cname)
{
  size_t i;

  do
  {
    printf("Enter Customer Name: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    if (1 != scanf(STR_FMT(CNAME_MAX_LEN), cname))
      return 1;

    for (i = 0; isalpha(cname[i]); ++i);
  }
  while (i == 0 || cname[i]);

  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  char cname[CNAME_MAX_LEN + 1];

  if (inputName(cname))
  {
    perror("error reading in name!\n");
    return 1;
  }

  printf("cname is '%s'\n", cname);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strspn()` to test the string like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char str[100] = {0};
    int len;
    scanf ("%99s", str);
    len = strlen(str);
    if (len != strspn(str, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
        printf ("Your string contains non-alphabet characters.\n");
    else
        printf ("Your string is good.\n");
    return 0;
}
```